# Product Collection in entry.php

Tags: magento2, product, api

We wants to display the product collection in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Gallery/entry.php

Thanks

Comment: its core file of magento - you want to display your product collection in core file ?

Comment: yes, @ Manthan Dave

Comment: further i will over ride the core file

Answer (score 0):

**First extend this file and then try this , may be it will help you :**

```
/**
  * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
  */

     protected $_registry;

     /**
     * ...
     * ...
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
     */
    public function __construct(
        ...,
        ...,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        ...
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        ...
        ...
    }

    /**
     * Return catalog product object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }
```

Comment: thanks for replay. but we tried this but it's not working.